# alphanumeric with at least 1 character

Tags: c#, regex

Ok so I finally figured out that I need the following:

So the regular expression has to perform:

1. alphanumeric
2. at least 1 **letter**
3. must have between 4 and 8 **characters** (either a letter/digit).

i.e. an alphanumeric string, that must have at least 1 letter, and be between 4-8 in length. (so it can't be just all numbers or just all letters).

can all of this be done in a single regex?

Comment: by character I meant letter, while 4-8 I meant any alpha.

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming you mean alphaunumeric, at least one *letter*, and 4 to 8 characters long.

Try this:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}
```

- `(?=` - we're using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so we can check for something without affecting the rest of the match
- `.*[a-zA-Z]` - match for anything followed by a letter, i.e. check we have at least one letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}` - This will match a letter or a number 4 to 8 times.

However, you say the intention is for "it can't be just all numbers or just all letters", but requirements 1, 2 and 3 don't accomplish this since it's can be all letters and meet all three requirements.  It's possible you want this, with an extra lookahead to confirm there's at least one digit:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}
```

The use of `a-zA-Z` isn't very international friendly, so you may be better off using an escape code for "letter" if available in your flavour of Regular Expressions.

Also, I hope this isn't matching for acceptable passwords, as 4 characters probably isn't long enough.

Comment: It shouldn't be .+ since then it wouldn't match 1aaa for example.

Comment: @Dave: you are wrong. .+ means at least **one** but .* cound match by eg. "1111". ?Regex.IsMatch("1aaa", "(?=.+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}")
**true**; ?Regex.IsMatch("1111", "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}")
**false**

Comment: The lookahead is there to check if a letter is in the pattern, that is all, which is why it uses * as there letter can appear anywhere in the patter, even first.  What I should have said is that if I use .+ the it won't match a111 (not 1aaa).

Answer (score 1):

number 2 and 3 seem to contradict. The following will match alphanumeric between 4 and 8:

```
/[0-9a-zA-Z]{4,8}/
```

Comment: 2 doesn't contradict 3, but is redundant.

Comment: @Nick Dixon- depends what you interpret them as meaning!

Answer (score 1):

```
?Regex.IsMatch("sdf", "(?=.+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}")
false
?Regex.IsMatch("sdfd", "(?=.+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}")
true
?Regex.IsMatch("1234", "(?=.+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}")
false
```

**Warning on **.*** and **.+**:

```
// At least one letter does not match with .*
?Regex.IsMatch("1111", "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}")
false

?Regex.IsMatch("1aaa", "(?=.+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}")
true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}
```

The first part specifies alphanumeric, and the 2nd part specifies from 4 to 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try: [a-zA-Z0-9]{4,8}